# How to merge multiple PDF's in native ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf-generation

I am looking for a solution to this issue but I have not yet found anything conclusive. I would love to get some input. What I need to do is basically to take two or more individual PDF-files and merge them into one. Nothing fancy just sticking one after the other and ending up with one file.

I have found [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) and purePDF but those libs both seem to be focused towards generating PDF's from scratch.

I would greatly appreciate any input on this. Thx.

Comment: Can't you read PDF files and extract pages by using the libs you mentioned? Then, you can maybe merge them and create new PDF files.

Comment: It seems that PurePDF is very close to letting me do something like this. However, I would have to port additional code from the iText (Java) library.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you can merge PDF files on the client side, but if nothing is left over (and the files aren't too large) you could send them to the server. There you have the choice between your favorite PDF merge tool or library (e.g. [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)).

Comment: I will need to do quite a lot of merges so offloading this to the client would be very useful. Thx anyways.

Comment: @madsmao, in this case the question is, if Flash Player is the right platform for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge PDFs in AS3.

The best you can do is load PDF files and do minor javascript scripting of the HTMLLoader (AIR only) instance into which the PDF is loaded. See [Known limitations for PDF content in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7eb4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cfe) for more.